# Custom jQuery accordion - scroll to top of the active panel

Tags: jquery, scrolltop, jquery-ui-accordion

I have an issue with a custom jQuery accordion. I cannot use the accordion in jQuery UI, therefore I'm stuck with the custom solution.

I created a fiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/1x11ceev/9/

My jQuery:

```
var allPanels = $('#accordion > .acc-item > .container > .content-text').hide();

$('#accordion > .acc-item').click(function() {

    if ($(this).hasClass('active')) {
        allPanels.slideUp();
        allPanels.parent().parent().removeClass('active');
    }else{
    allPanels.slideUp();
    allPanels.parent().parent().removeClass('active');
    $(this).addClass('active');
    $(this).children().children('.content-text').slideDown();
       return false;
    }
    $('html, body').animate({scrollTop: $(this).offset().top + 100 }, 'slow');

});`
```

What I need is have the active panel slide to top (with an offset too as I have a fixed header). I tried using ScrollTop but to no avail.
The current behaviour:
If I expand the first section, then scroll down to the second section and expand it, the first section collapses, therefore the height of the document decreases and then the second section is pulled up, out of viewport.

My jQuery skills are limited. Any help is appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: When you say "slide to the top" do you mean that you want the second section to move to the top of the accordion when clicked on, for example? the same would apply to third section?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this.

What you need to do is, move the scroll only after the Active slide's animation has been completed. `slideDown` accepts a function as a complete callback. So I moved your scroll code to this function.

And to have some margin from top, 100 should be minus not added to the `scrollTop`.

```js
var allPanels = $('#accordion > .acc-item > .container > .content-text').hide();
    
   $('#accordion > .acc-item').click(function() {

    if ($(this).hasClass('active')) {
     allPanels.slideUp();
     allPanels.parent().parent().removeClass('active');
    }else{
     allPanels.slideUp();
     allPanels.parent().parent().removeClass('active');
     $(this).addClass('active');
     $(this).children().children('.content-text').slideDown(
            function(){
                debugger;
                $('html, body').animate({scrollTop: $(this).offset().top - 100 }, 'slow');
            }
        );
           return false;
     }
        

 });
```

```css
.acc-item { padding:45px 0 50px;}

#icecream { background:#ccc;}
#shakes { background: #ddd;}
#floats { background: #bbb;}
.acc-item .content-text{}
.acc-item h3 { margin:0}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="fillerText">
    <p>At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, At accusam aliquyam diam diam dolore dolores duo eirmod eos erat, et nonumy sed tempor et et invidunt justo labore Stet clita ea et gubergren, kasd magna no rebum. sanctus sea sed takimata ut vero voluptua. est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat.</p>
</div>

<div id="accordion">

    <div id="icecream" class="home-section acc-item">
     <div class="container clear">
            <h3>FIRST SECTION</h3>
            <div class="content-text">
                <p>Nam liber tempor cum soluta nobis eleifend option congue nihil imperdiet doming id quod mazim placerat facer possim assum. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat. Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exerci tation ullamcorper suscipit lobortis nisl ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
                <p>Nam liber tempor cum soluta nobis eleifend option congue nihil imperdiet doming id quod mazim placerat facer possim assum. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat. Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exerci tation ullamcorper suscipit lobortis nisl ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
                <p>Nam liber tempor cum soluta nobis eleifend option congue nihil imperdiet doming id quod mazim placerat facer possim assum. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat. Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exerci tation ullamcorper suscipit lobortis nisl ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
                <p>Nam liber tempor cum soluta nobis eleifend option congue nihil imperdiet doming id quod mazim placerat facer possim assum. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat. Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exerci tation ullamcorper suscipit lobortis nisl ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
            </div>
  </div><!--.container-->
 </div><!--#icecream-->

    <div id="shakes" class="home-section acc-item">
  <div class="container clear">
            <h3>SECOND SECTION</h3>
            <div class="content-text">
                <p>Nam liber tempor cum soluta nobis eleifend option congue nihil imperdiet doming id quod mazim placerat facer possim assum. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat. Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exerci tation ullamcorper suscipit lobortis nisl ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
            </div>
        </div><!--.container-->
    </div><!--#shakes-->

 <div id="floats" class="home-section acc-item">
  <div class="container clear">
             <h3>THIRD SECTION</h3>
            <div class="content-text">
                <p>Nam liber tempor cum soluta nobis eleifend option congue nihil imperdiet doming id quod mazim placerat facer possim assum. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat. Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exerci tation ullamcorper suscipit lobortis nisl ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
                <p>Nam liber tempor cum soluta nobis eleifend option congue nihil imperdiet doming id quod mazim placerat facer possim assum. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat. Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exerci tation ullamcorper suscipit lobortis nisl ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
                <p>Nam liber tempor cum soluta nobis eleifend option congue nihil imperdiet doming id quod mazim placerat facer possim assum. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat. Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exerci tation ullamcorper suscipit lobortis nisl ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
            </div>
  </div><!--.container-->
 </div><!--#floats-->   
</div><!--#accordion-->

<div class="fillerText">
    <p>At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, At accusam aliquyam diam diam dolore dolores duo eirmod eos erat, et nonumy sed tempor et et invidunt justo labore Stet clita ea et gubergren, kasd magna no rebum. sanctus sea sed takimata ut vero voluptua. est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat.</p><p>At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, At accusam aliquyam diam diam dolore dolores duo eirmod eos erat, et nonumy sed tempor et et invidunt justo labore Stet clita ea et gubergren, kasd magna no rebum. sanctus sea sed takimata ut vero voluptua. est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat.</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you. You made it very clear where I was wrong in my coding.